# How to transform xml data to csv on Azure logic app

Tags: xml, azure, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to grab the XML from the URI below and transform it into a csv file. How do I go about doing this with an Azure Logic app?

https://reportservices.crediblebh.com/reports/ExportService.asmx/ExportXML?connection=Y!KcFwIoIa1BZLzJnKfEshACoW10Rtw!DmvWxFkFgsUiJmP34wHKBMB9VD1YcnuRPQewAfLGSdDOiQXdvGiURA__&start_date=&end_date=&custom_param1=&custom_param2=&custom_param3=

Step 1 in my Logic app is a HTTP trigger using the GET method:

[HTTP trigger with GET method and URI containing the XML I want to parse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYmcf.png)

When I run Step 1 I get the following:

[Result after running Step 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6Hk7.png)

Essentially I want to parse the Body of of the HTTP trigger (Step 1) into a csv file. In other words I want to transform this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="https://www.crediblebh.com/">&lt;NewDataSet&gt;
  &lt;Table&gt;
    &lt;client_id&gt;-99999&lt;/client_id&gt;
    &lt;clientprogramscount&gt;80066&lt;/clientprogramscount&gt;
    &lt;teamclientcount&gt;68247&lt;/teamclientcount&gt;
    &lt;employeeclientscount&gt;40415&lt;/employeeclientscount&gt;
    &lt;questioncount&gt;190954&lt;/questioncount&gt;
    &lt;answercount&gt;463010&lt;/answercount&gt;
    &lt;delvisitcount&gt;7484&lt;/delvisitcount&gt;
    &lt;savedvisitanswercount&gt;6950104&lt;/savedvisitanswercount&gt;
    &lt;cntclientsext&gt;60330&lt;/cntclientsext&gt;
    &lt;cntclientepisode&gt;68069&lt;/cntclientepisode&gt;
    &lt;cntclientvisit&gt;487500&lt;/cntclientvisit&gt;
    &lt;cntchangelog&gt;13231067&lt;/cntchangelog&gt;
    &lt;cntchangelogdetail&gt;1272642&lt;/cntchangelogdetail&gt;
    &lt;cntclientvisitapproval&gt;29540&lt;/cntclientvisitapproval&gt;
  &lt;/Table&gt;
&lt;/NewDataSet&gt;</string>
```

into the following csv:

client_id,clientprogramscount,teamclientcount,employeeclientscount,questioncount,answercount,delvisitcount,savedvisitanswercount,cntclientsext,cntclientepisode,cntclientvisit,cntchangelog,cntchangelog,cntchangelogdetail,cntclientvisitapproval
-99999,80066,68247,40415,190954,463010,7484,6950104,60330,68069,487500,13231067,13231067,1272642,29540

Sorry that I can't show the actual images in my post because apparently I don't have enough reputation points to embed actual images yet.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: First of all welcome to Stackoverflow. It would be nice if you can please refine your question a bit. For example the image is missing. Also As per my knowledge there are no free XML to CSV converter. There are a few paid softwares available. The best you can do is write a custom azure function to convert XML to CSV.

Comment: @TikluGanguly Hi Tiklu, thank you for your feedback! I tried pasting the actual images in my post but I keep getting a message saying that I don't have enough reputation points to do that, so I have to use links to the images for now. I've also made some edits to my post to make the problem clearer. Please let me know if that helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You many want to use "Flat File Encoding" action in Logic App.

For this, you should create a schema, which would map the XML fields into CSV format that you require -> place that schema in Integration Account -> use this schema in "Flat File Encoding" action in Logic App to transform XML data to CSV format.
Take a look at this [Encode and decode flat files in Azure Logic Apps by using the Enterprise Integration Pack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-enterprise-integration-flatfile)

If Integration Account option seems expensive, use a custom Azure Function that does the schema functioning (XML->CSV) and use Azure Function action in Logic App.